# HTML CSS Header images not floating correctly

Tags: html, css

Afternoon all,

I'm trying to create a basic header

White space at top with an image that floats left and an image that floats right.

Then below this a grey background with some options and a button on left and some nav buttons on right.

The requirements are that the header will always be 100% width and that when you scroll down the page the header always stays at the top.

I have this working fine with my current HTML and CSS however when I reduce screen size e.g. snap right on my laptop 1368x768 resolution on laptop the image on the right floats below the buttons on the right hand side but inside the grey border?!

Left image size = 480x80
Right image size = 264x80

HTML

```
<div id="banner">
        <img src="/images/img1.png" style="float:left"/>
        <img src="/images/img2.png" style="float:right"/>
    </div> 

<div id="header">
<div id="header_left">
    <form action= "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method ="POST">
        <select name=dbselector>
            <?php
                echo '<option value="1"';
                    if ($_COOKIE[$cookie] == "x") {
                        echo ' selected="selected"';}
                            echo '>1</option>';
                echo '<option value="2"'; 
                    if ($_COOKIE[$cookie] == "y") 
                        {echo ' selected="selected"';}
                            echo '>2</option>';
            ?>
        </select>
        <input name="submit_button" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="header_right">
    <?php date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London'); echo date('h:i:s');?> 
    <input type="button" value="Back" onclick="history.go(-1)">
    <a href="www.google.co.uk" style="text-decoration: none"> 
        <input type="button" value="Home">
    </a>
    <input type="button" value="Refresh" onClick="history.go(0)" >
    <input type="button" value="Forward" onclick="history.go(1)">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#header 
{
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
background:#58575b;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom:0.5em;
margin: 0px
}

#banner
{
background:#fff;
width:100%;
height: 5em;
}

#header_left
{
float: left;
padding: 0em;
padding-left: 0.5em;
margin: 0em;
}

#header_right
{
float: right;
padding: 0em;
margin: 0em;
padding-right: 0.5em;
}
```

Any ideas why it is behaving like this?!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please upload a fiddle so we can test it ourselves and better help you. jsfiddle.net

Comment: Odd I cant seem to recreate the issue in jsfiddle it works as expected

Comment: This is line for line the same as my code that im using on site
https://jsfiddle.net/92xs18hs/2/ works fine in jsfiddle but not IE or Firefox

Answer (score 0):

In a few comments of the starting post you say something about it not working properly in Internet explorer or Firefox.

It works in chrome right?

So it may be such a thing something isn't compatible with firefox or IE.

Not many use IE for the fact it is decommissioned by microsoft.

So, now let's focus just on Firefox and smaller screens as that also seems to be a issue.

Solution for small screens: Use viewports or media queries (either or should fix it)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

For the issues with FireFox can you explain what it does? You just mention the issue for small screens exactly what it is doing but didn't explain the issues with Firefox  (IE)

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry mate see above for resolution, and im not sure what you mean not many people use IE as its Windows Enterprise browser?!?!

Comment: It has been decomissioned by Microsoft and is very insecure, the only people who use it is businesses or the gov't which are mostly on private networks with more secure firewalls

Comment: If you fixed it, then you need to edit your question, however, your answer is not explained throughly or anything, so thats why it was downvoted (not by me) the idea is stackoverflow is a directory where if someone else gains the same issue that there is a solution at hand

Comment: The solution is very clear please see below the very first line is: "Solution was very basic" also IE has not been decomissioned by Microsoft?! the comment "The only people who it is businesses or the gov't" well this site is aimed at these users not home end users

Comment: They announced it and it was in all the major computer journals/online blogs

Answer (score -1):

Solution was very basic...

The only thing different between the jsfiddle and my live code were the images.

I have checked the images and they have loads of whitespace in them hence why it moves down!

Took the images straight of our corporate site so I didn't even both to check for whitespace in the image itself.....

Argh!